# Create new string json in php from ajax call

Tags: php, json

I have a html page with this page, when i submit form i send ajax data like this:

```
array(7) { ["idfornitore"]=> string(1) "1" ["criterio-5"]=> string(1) "4" ["voto-5"]=> string(1) "1" ["parziale-5"]=> string(1) "4" ["criterio-3"]=> string(1) "2" ["voto-3"]=> string(1) "3" ["parziale-3"]=> string(1) "6"}
```

Example:

```
["criterio-5"] => string(1) "4" ["voto-5"]=> string(1) "1" ["parziale-5"]=> string(1) "4"
["criterio-5"] => is "weight of criterio5"
["voto-5"]     => is "value of criterio5"
["parziale-5"] => is "totale of criterio5" ( weight * value )
```

## My service php do this:

```
$totale = 0;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (strstr($key, "parziale")) {
        $totale = $totale + $value;
    }
}
```

==================================

I would scorrermi the array and form a string json so 'made:

```
{    
    "parziali": [
        {"idcriterio": "5", "peso": "4" , "voto": "1", "parziale": "5" },
        {"idcriterio": "3", "peso": "2" , "peso": "3", "peso": "6" }
    ]
}
```

How can I do?

Comment: I don't know how you're planning to make that JSON string from your foreach function that calculates a total.

Answer (score 0):

this look similar to building xml elements -- build tuples of {criterio, voto, parziale} where the tags are suffixed with the criterio value

```
$tuples = array();
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    list($field, $suffix) = explode($key);
    if ($field === 'idcriterio') {
      $tuples[$suffix] = $suffix;
      $tuples['peso'] = $value;
  }
  else {
      $tuples[$suffix][$field] = $value;
  }
}

$json = json_encode($tuples);
```

I don't understand how `parziale` is computed, but you get the idea